# Resource Dictionaries

Tags: c#, wpf

I've wrote a converter that takes a string and returns a resource dictionary and works like a charm but if i want to use the same resource dictionary in 2 places, the first resource dictionary will disappear from the first place and i really don't understand why. ( This resource dictionaries are some vector images placed in a Viewbox ).

Do you guys have any ideas?

Here is my converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     if (value != null)
     {
        var temp= Application.Current.TryFindResource(value);
        if (temp!= null)
        {
           return temp;
        }
     }
     return null;
  }
```

Comment: "This resource dictionaries are some vector images placed in a Viewbox" implies that you have UI elements as resources. But you can't add a UI element to two or more parent/container controls at the same time. The upshot is that you should not have UI element resources in the first place. Use geometries or drawings instead.

Comment: @Rock3rRullz, you can try setting [`x:Shared="false"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778(v=vs.110).aspx) on your resources

Comment: @dkozl Please put your answer as a replay to my question so i can mark it as correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your resources are `Visual` it means they can only have one parent so if you use same instance in another place of visual tree it will be removed from previous place. One way to solve your problem is to set [`x:Shared="false"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) against your resource

> **x:Shared="false"** behavior creates another identical instance of the resource instead of returning the same instance